# How do I initialize LLVM's external symbolizer?

Tags: runtime-error, clang, llvm, debug-symbols

When compiling with `-fsanitize=memory` I get `WARNING: Trying to symbolize code, but external symbolizer is not initialized!` when running the program. How do I initialize the external symbolizer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved my own problem using `MSAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=$(which llvm-symbolizer-3.4) ./a.out`. The problem is that Ubuntu postfixes the version number but the binary doesn't know that. Of course you need to use `MSAN` instead of `ASAN` when using the memory sanitizer.

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to be able to set the ASAN_FILTER environment variable to point at a symbolizer, but I could not get it to work.  However, you can redirect stderr into a symbolizer after the fact.  You'll still get the warnings about the uninitialized symbolizer, but the filenames and line numbers will be correct.

You can use [asan_symbolizer.py](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/lib/asan/scripts/asan_symbolize.py) as the external symbolizer. After downloading it from that link (to /tmp, for example), invoke your program like so (in bash, for this example):

```
./myprogram 2>&1 | /tmp/asan_symbolize.py | c++filt
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu system, the issue is that LLVM's tools are installed under `/usr/bin` with version suffixes (like `llvm-symbolizer-4.0`), and the sanitizer tools are looking for them without version suffixes.

LLVM also installs its binaries to, e.g., `/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/bin`; the tools under `/usr/bin` are actually just symlinks. So an easy solution is to add the appropriate `/usr/lib/llvm-*/bin` directory to your path when working with sanitizers.

Answer (score 0):

I received such warning when I run program debug version (compiled with `-fsanitize=address`) on Linux machine that didn't contain `clang` installation. The problem disappeared after I installed `clang` from `devtoolset`.